# Detect hover/mouseover/mouseenter while dragging an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

How to detect hover/mouseover/mouseenter while dragging an element? I want to have green box after hovering it with the "drag" element. Is there any solution for that?

Note: I know that I could use jQuery UI for it but I want to do it by myself.

```
    $("box").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("green");
  var box = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#result").html(box);
});

$("box").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("green");
});

$("drag").bind({
  mousedown: function() {
    $(this).addClass("absolute");
  },
  mouseup: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("absolute");
  },
  mousemove: function(e) {
    $(this).css({
      left: e.pageX - (50 / 2),
      top: e.pageY - (50 / 2)
    });
  }
});

$("body").mousemove(function(event) {
  $("#log").text("pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/38zecoL1/1/

Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Rick that's a bit unfair of you... He's attempting to get it done and is having an issue with one small part. It's not bad practice to write features of an existing library just to know how things work / to say you have.

Comment: Use html5 drag/drop events... https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: There is an interesting experimental API to figure out multiple elements at a particular `(x,y)` position. [`document.elementsFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint). Maybe use the `mousemove` event on the body to check if both `box2` and `drag` are at the same position.

Answer (score 7):

I would try to disable pointer events on the dragged object using: `pointer-events: none;`. That way you should get the events of the hovered objects instead of the dragged.

But you also need to adapt to the situation that the move and mouseup event will not work. You will have to bind them elsewhere (body for example)

This short example is not perfect but schuld give you a hint of how to do it better ;)

```js
$("box").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("green");
    var box = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#result").html(box);
});

$("box").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("green");
});

$("#drag").bind({
    mousedown : function (e) {
        $(document.body).css({ 'user-select': 'none' })
        var dragged = $(this);
        dragged.css({
            left : e.pageX - (50 / 2),
            top : e.pageY - (50 / 2)
        });
        dragged.css({
            'pointer-events' : 'none'
        })
        var upHandler = function () {
            dragged.removeClass("absolute");
            dragged.css({
                'pointer-events' : 'all'
            })
            $(document.body).css({ 'user-select': 'initial' })
            $("body").off('mouseup', upHandler);
            $("body").off('mousemove', moveHandler);
        }
        var moveHandler = function (e) {
            dragged.addClass("absolute");
            dragged.css({
                left : e.pageX - (50 / 2),
                top : e.pageY - (50 / 2)
            });
        }

        $("body").bind({
            mouseup : upHandler,
            mousemove : moveHandler
        })
    }
});

$("body").mousemove(function (event) {
    $("#log").text("pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY);
});
```

```css
box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

#log {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

#drag {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

#drag.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<box id="box1">
  <div id="drag"></div>
</box>
<box id="box2"></box>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your feedback, I'm one step closer to achieve my own drag and drop function! ;)

Comment: Hello again. I found issue with pointer-events. When I drag element, sometimes appears "not allowed" cursor and I can't drag this element anymore. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: This happens because the browser tries to move the "selected content". Add `$(document.body).css({ 'user-select': 'none' })` at the start of the drag, and `$(document.body).css({ 'user-select': 'initial' })` at the end of the drag. (see edit of my code)

Comment: "I would try to disable pointer events on the dragged object using: pointer-events: none" - GENIUS!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the container stays green and the other one doesn't change is that the element you're dragging is a child of the first container. So while your mouse is in the blue draggable box it's still considered inside the container on the left because the blue box is a child of the first  container.

One way to fix this (and most likely isn't the best way) is to keep track of where the mouse is on the screen (which you're already doing to move the blue block). In there if you add a bit of code checking if the mouse is within the bounding box of either of the other containers and add/remove classes based on that. Then the classes will be added based on mouse position and not whether the mouse is over an element that is a child or is not a child.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/38zecoL1/3/

```
      var boxes = $("box")
      for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
        var boundingBox = boxes[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        if(e.pageX < boundingBox.right &&
             e.pageX > boundingBox.left &&
           e.pageY < boundingBox.bottom &&
           e.pageY > boundingBox.top){
          $(boxes[i]).addClass("green");
        } else{
          $(boxes[i]).removeClass("green");
        }
      }
```

This is likely pretty expensive to add in a page that deals with a more complex page than just a few divs and may not perform well in those more complex situations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helped me a lot.

Comment: For sure, I think a lot of people on here forget to explain why things are happening and just give a solution. Glad to help though.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to drag element I recommend you to use this JS library https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

There is an opt called

`chosenClass: "sortable-chosen",  // Class name for the chosen item`

and in this class you can add different color and everything you want.

But if you wanto to do this by yourself i don't now

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but as I said, I want to do it in pure jQuery.